# SQLCLR and Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server..ctor()

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I'm having a massive problem with my clr stored proc written in c#. I have successfully installed the assembly but when i call the stored proc i get the below error:-

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure RestoreDatabaseClr, Line 0

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or     aggregate "RestoreDatabaseClr": 

System.Exception: This functionality is disabled in the SQLCLR. It is recommended that you execute from your client application.
System.Exception: 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager..ctor()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection..ctor()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager..ctor(String name)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server..ctor()
at DBRestoreClr.StoredProcedures.RestoreDatabaseClr(String backupFile, String dbName, String dataFiles, String logFiles)
```

.

This is c# code i am trying to execute with in the sproc:-

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace DBRestoreClr
{
    public partial class StoredProcedures
    {
        [SqlProcedure()]
        public static int RestoreDatabaseClr(string backupFile, string dbName, string dataFiles, string logFiles)
        {
             var sqlServer = new Server();
        }
    }
}
```

i'm executing using the below

```
EXEC @ReturnValue RestoreDatabaseClr 'C:\Workspace\DEV\DBRestoreDatabase\tests\Clr\restore.bak', 
                            'restore',
                            'C:\2008\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\restore',
                            'C:\2008\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\restore\logs';
```

Any one have any ideas why its not working?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Why are you adding a non-standard replacement for the `RESTORE DATABASE` T-SQL command?

Comment: because our live estate has about 100 db files (inc logs) and we need this restoring to dev on occasions, so i want to write a clr to loop through these db files in the backup and move them to a new location on restore. and the smo classes provider perfect libries for this hence the clr. I've found a different approach now - i'm sticking with the clr but removing the smo classes and using inline sql i.e. "RESTORE FILESIONLY" with SqlConnection and SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapters\DataSets for the loop through the files - works perfectly,

Comment: i dynmically generate the restore statement and pass it sql with the "WITH MOVE" in the concatenated sql string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "This functionality is disabled in the SQLCLR". The SMO framework detects that you are in SQL CLR and refuses to work. The reason for that is probably that it was to costly for Microsoft to make it all work, which is a valid reason.

Why don't you just restore the database from your client program, just as the message suggests?